# Reloading an entity does not trigger NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I'm having two properties, one is a collection named `Items` and the other is an `Item`. The collection is bind to a Datagrid and when I double click on the datagrid, the selection is loaded into `Item` that is binded to a textbox via `Item.Name`. When I modify the text into the textbox, the changes are reflected into the Datagrid thanks to  `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. My problem is that when I cancel this changes, I reload the entity from db with `_context.Entry(Item).Reload();` but the `OnPropertyChanged` it's never triggered. I also tried to call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Item))` after the reload but with no succes. The only thing that seems to work is the fallowing:

```
 _itemRepository.Reload(Item);
 Item.Name = Item.Name;
 //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Post));
```

Is this a bug or a feature? How can I update my UI without using this hack.
I'm using WPF on .NET 5 with EF Core 5.

Item Model:

```
public class Item : BaseEntity
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Until I have some time to test in a minimal environment, like [BionicCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859661/reloading-an-entity-does-not-trigger-notifypropertychanged#comment121714947_68863477) sugested, I got a quick fix:

`Datagrid.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: Can you show your models classes?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is disconnecting the entity from the PropertyChanged infrastructure to improve performance during internal entity manipulations. You would have to enable property change propagation explicitly by configuring the `DbContext` and its associated model(s) to use the appropriate tracking strategy.This is done by using the `ModelBuilder`.

For example, if your entity is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` alone, setting the change tracking strategy to `ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangedNotifications` would be sufficient. If it also implements `INotifyPropertyChanging` use `ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangingAndChangedNotifications` or any other appropriate enumeration value that includes enabling changed notifications. See [`ChangeTrackingStrategy` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.changetrackingstrategy?view=efcore-1.1#fields) to find more available configuration values or to get an explanation.

To use the `ModelBuilder` you must override the virtual `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext`:

```
public class ItemsContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

  ...

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
      .HasChangeTrackingStrategy(ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangedNotifications);
  }
}
```

Comment: I must do something wrong because I got the same results. I'll try to go deeper on `ChangeTrackingStrategy`. Thank you!

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, then there must be more issues with your code. I recommend to set up a blank project with a minimal test environment and see if the fix works. Then compare this to your production environment.